# XML Remove node if exist with SelectSingleNode

Tags: xml, powershell

I try to build up a powershell script that removes a node from my web.config file if the node exist.
I have following xml structure

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging, Version=2.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e" />
    </sectionGroup>

  </configSections>
</configuration>
```

And following code:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $WebAppConfigPath

 $addSectionGroupNode = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//configuration/configSections/sectionGroup/add[@name='common']")
  if ($addSectionGroupNode -ne $null)
  {
    $SectionGroupNode.RemoveChild($addSectionGroupNode)
    Write-Host "REMOVED"
  }

  $xml.Save($WebAppConfigPath)
```

However, the node cannot be found and is not removed. 
Can you please help me get the right command?

Thank you

Comment: How is `$SectionGroupNode` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> //configuration/configSections/sectionGroup/add[@name='common']
> ```

Amongst other criteria that is looking for an `<add>` element immediately inside a `<sectionGroup>`, and there is no such element.

Did you mean to use

```
/configuration/configSections/sectionGroup[@name='common']
```

?

Note, as `<configuration>` is the root element of the XML document using `//` at the start of the expression can only slow things down.